# I am having issues with futurebuilder with list view builder | flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, snapshot

I try to get data from the API but not getting data. just getting instance of ModelName...
I am also not able to get the length of the **snapshot.data.length**. I read some blogs but didn't work it.

I have provided the code down below with the model.
please help me to get out of this problem. I am new to flutter and some youtube video's are old.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:chaitanya_academy/models/exam_result_model.dart';
import 'package:chaitanya_academy/screens/DetailResult.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ResultsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ResultsScreen> createState() => _ResultsScreenState();
}

class _ResultsScreenState extends State<ResultsScreen> {
  Future<ResultModel> getResults() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = await prefs.getString('token');
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/api/student/results'),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': "Bearer $token",
      },
    );
    return ResultModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getResults();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My Results')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: FutureBuilder<ResultModel>(
          future: getResults(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    leading: const Icon(
                      Icons.menu_book,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    // title: Text(snapshot.data[1].examId.toString()),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.visibility),
                    onTap: () {
                      // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailResult()));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class ResultModel {
  int? examId;
  String? examName;
  int? examStream;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  ResultModel(
      {this.examId,
      this.examName,
      this.examStream,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  ResultModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    examId = json['exam_id'];
    examName = json['exam_name'];
    examStream = json['exam_stream'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['exam_id'] = this.examId;
    data['exam_name'] = this.examName;
    data['exam_stream'] = this.examStream;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: you might require to change localhost to the internal IP address, there is some configuration you'd have to do in order to use localhost via device/emulator.

Comment: I did it Rishabh Sir, but getting the same error. I am not able to display the data into list.

Comment: how can you make sure that your API is call from the App

Comment: add a debugger in the if statement " if (snapshot.hasData) {"

Comment: i am using print() function but it is returning instance of ResultModel

Comment: write this about print  ResultModel  resultModel  = snapshot.data as ResultModel; and print(resultModel.examId)

Comment: but i am sending an array of an object from the backend not a single object sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246536/discussion-between-rishabh-agrawal-and-swapnil-mane).

Answer (score 0):

You have to store snapshot.data by creating object of its class ResultModel like this:
ResultModel snapshotData = snapshot.data;
then you can easily access the various properties of your snapshotData object

Comment: A value of type 'ResultModel?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ResultModel'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'ResultModel'. getting this errror...

Comment: use as: ResultModel snapshotData = snapshot.data  as ResultModel;

Comment: How can i access the first element of that list/array ??

Comment: snapshotData is an instance of ResultModel since your future returns ResultModel object. So you can access keys on snapshotData object like snapShot.examId

Comment: but sir i am sending an array from the backend.

Comment: Check your future's return type. It's ResultModel. If you are intending to return List then you should change return type to List.

Comment: I have changes return type to List but I am getting error at the end of the function **return ...** how can i solve that error ??

Comment: It's not working though